# Windows 7 Basic Magnifier "Full Screen" option grayed out

Tags: windows-7

PC with Windows 7 Home Basic.

Magnifier options

- Full Screen (Ctrl Alt F)
- Lens   (Ctrl Alt L)
- Docked  (Ctrl Alt D)
- Preview Full Screen  (Ctrl Alt Space)

Only the **Docked** option is enabled.  The short-cut keys do not work either

Is it possible to enable the other options in "Home Basic" or do I need to upgrade to "Home Premium"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help file (press F1):

> "Full-screen mode and lens mode are only available as part of the Aero
>   experience. If your computer doesn't support Aero, or if you're using
>   a theme other than an Aero theme, Magnifier will only work in docked
>   mode."

I am sorry, but Home Basic does not include Aero. From the following link:

> "The Aero desktop experience, available in the Home Premium,
>   Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions of Windows 7..."

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/aero

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll install Home Premium and report back.

Comment: @pauly Thank you for marking it. Keep in mind that you have to actually use Aero (enable an Aero theme).

Comment: Same problem on Windows 7 Enterprise 
https://superuser.com/questions/1506728/full-screen-and-lens-mode-in-magnifier-windows-7-enterprise-grayed-out

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that it is a problem with your display adapter. Some do not support full-screen functions.

You could go to your computer manufacturer's web-site and check for the latest graphics driver. If not there, try the manufacturer of your graphics "card".

It is most likely not a function of what version of Windows you are running, but of the type and capabilities of your display adapter.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately re-installed the display adapter didn't do the trick.